# Regarding GCM from multiple applications

Tags: android, android-c2dm

Hi I had used C2DM in my application to push messages. Now I have migrated to GCM and through it I can push messages to android application.

More over there's one feature of GCM , through which two or more server applications can push messages to android application. How this feature can be implemented. For exaemple I have a news feed application from one provider. Now along with the news updates  some  third party local offers vendors can also push the offers updates.

Thanks

Comment: If you did GCM app before this is not a big task.... Can you explain more your problem?

Comment: yup .. this could be an easy task...but how third party application server would be integrated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating google Api project for Gcm you will get the id for your project.

This id is unique for your project (and you can use this in many of your application).

Using this project id you can register your device to GCM;after registering successfully on Gcm,Gcm will return you an **registration id**(also called as PUSH_TOKEN).

using this **registration id and project id**, many server can send notification to device.

to receive the notification from server you need to implement **GCMIntentService class**.

and you will receive your messages in `onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1)` method.

I strongly recommend you to have a look at [Getting started with GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)

Document also says that,Gcm allows multiple sender  are passed as an intent extra in a comma-separated list
As,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GCMConstants.INTENT_TO_GCM_REGISTRATION);
intent.setPackage(GSF_PACKAGE);
intent.putExtra(GCMConstants.EXTRA_APPLICATION_PENDING_INTENT,
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0));
String senderIds = "968350041068,652183961211";
intent.putExtra(GCMConstants.EXTRA_SENDER, senderIds);
ontext.startService(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer dd619.. but how  would I get new project ID for different third party application.. ?

Comment: ask each third-party for their project ID;they will provide you(remember that they are also registered with Gcm).

Comment: oh..can't I get the third party project ID programatecally, after confirming to Google OAuth flow..

Comment: no,you can't get project id problematically; it is private for third-party server.

Comment: hmm.. ok I will find out a solution for this.. Neways.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The code above has been there for a while and the package GCMConstants seems moved. Does anyone has a better updated code to register multiple sender?