# One GCM Project For Several Apps

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an automated system for APK generation. Each project has different application id but same package name.

Now we we want notifications in these apps and want to create only one Google Project for all apps.

Here is how it is going to look for two different projects:

Same (Package Name + SenderID + GCM Key + Device ID) + Different Application ID

1) Is this possible?

2) Will this be able to churn out different registration ids for two different projects. Because unless it does so, a user with two different apps with different application ids will get a notification twice.

Comment: This has already been answered in these SO posts - [Can i use one GCM project number in two different app for receive Push of GCM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757064/can-i-use-one-gcm-project-number-in-two-different-app-for-receive-push-of-gcm) and [Regarding GCM from multiple applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049239/regarding-gcm-from-multiple-applications). :)

Comment: Could you clarify what you are referring to as Application ID here?

Comment: Its application name attribute. The one we use here:

<application
            android:name=""
    />